# Creating nested movie clips

Tags: flash, flash-cs3, flashdevelop

I need to create 2 movie clips: clipA is be a wrapper movieclip. clipB is a container movieclip. There is about 15 pixels spacing between them. clipB is then passed to another function which add other elements to it ( buttons,graphics etc).
Whats the best way to get this done ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var clipA:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var clipB:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

clipB.x = clipA.x + clipA.width + 15;

this.addChild(clipA);
this.addChild(clipB);

otherFunction(clipB);
```

I'm not quite sure where you're going with this though, it seems like such a basic question.